# Many-to-many relationship with enum

Tags: python, enums, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I have models/tables with user and user group.

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):

    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        primary_key=True
    )
    username = db.Column(
        db.String(20),
        unique=True
    )
    [...]
    group_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('user_group.id'))
    group = db.relationship(UserGroup)
    [...]
```

```
class UserGroup(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "user_group"

    id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        primary_key=True
    )
    name = db.Column(
        db.String(32),
        unique=False
    )
    [...]
```

and enum with type of privileges

```
from enum import Enum


class UserGroupPrivilege(Enum):

    PAYMENTS = "payments"
    USERS_MANAGEMENT = "users_management"
    [...]
```

Is there any way to connect this to show and edit this in flask-admin in nice view?
Something like many-to-many relationship but with UserGroup to enum UserGroupPrivilege.

**I wants to get the effect where when I edit UserGroup I can add or remove privilages but choose them only from enum values.**
Same as users when I editing UserGroupPrivilege.

[image]

Comment: It's been almost exactly a year - were you found a solution @shinji? I'm running into the same question

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an answer to this question myself and it seems that this pattern is not usually done. An alternative is to replace the enum values with records that contain those values in their own table. Then you connect to that table with a many-to-many relationship.

For example, you could make a `UserGroupPrivilege` model instead of an Enum like this:

```py
class UserGroupPrivilege(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "user_group_privilege"

    id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        primary_key=True
    )
    name = db.Column(
        db.String(32),
        unique=False
    )
```

And then you could populate records in the database table for that model with the values for your enumerated options:

```
1,payments
2,users_management
```

You could make this data population step automated by using a fixture or data migration that occurs along with the schema migration you use to create the table in the database itself. It essentially accomplishes the same purpose as hard-coding your enum values, but is even better as it can be modified later in the database rather than having to change the code.

This is how I've got around the original problem you posted, and it's worked for me so far.